# Using REGEX and ORTH as part of phrasematching in SpaCy

Tags: python, spacy

I am using spacy's phrasematching for a large number of rules, some of these are company stock symbols which appear in the form of lets say:

AAPL.NY
BB.TX

Or these could appear as AAPL or BB.

When phrasematching I have been using two patterns to get these matches:

```
{"label": "TICKER", "pattern": [{"ORTH": {"REGEX": "AAPL\\.[A-Z]{2,3}"}}]}
{"label": "TICKER", "pattern": [{"ORTH": "AAPL"}]}
```

Is ORTH the right pattern to match for the REGEX? It gives some interesting results sometimes where it will capture something like AAPL.HSHSHSJSKKSKKS even though that is beyond the {2,3}.

Could anyone help me with
a) Whether using ORTH makes sense here
b) How would one limit the use of REGEX to only have a max of 2 or 3 characters after the period ?

Comment: Does my answer help or do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORTH` (meaning *orthography*) was used before `TEXT` was introduced in Spacy 2.1. Now, when doing regex matching, you'd better apply that to `TEXT`.

As for the regex itself, mind that it is applied to the whole token text, and in order to match the entire token text, you need to use *anchors*, `^` and `$`  (or `\A` and `\z`).

So, you can use

```py
{"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^AAPL\.[A-Z]{2,3}$"}}
```

Also, note the use of a raw string literal so as to avoid double escaping backslashes.